# Show post hits by IP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this code (together with another to display the result) for a visitor counter of each Wordpress post.

```
function setAndViewPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'views';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
return $count;}
```

It works fine, but it count a visit every time the page is refreshed.

Someone can guide me to the code I need to do the same but only count one IP visit or Some trick to at least keep me from getting someone not abusing the counter with repeated F5's.

Thanks.

Comment: IP != person so it wont count what you think it will.

Comment: set a cookie when u count.. and check it before u increase your counter

Answer (score 0):

Like @rtfm mentioned, an IP != person.

But if you want to count unique IP's that have visited, you should probably consider changing `$count_key` to store the IP's instead of storing a counter. Just use an array where the key is the IP address. Whenever you need the value, just do `count($count_key);`

No idea if wordpress allows storing an array using `add_post_meta()`, but if it doesn't you can just use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can count visits by IP, but this will require to keep a huge array with IP addresses and counts per address. Yes, you can store such in array via add_post_meta(), but database size will grow fast and performance degrade.

What you can do - just use cookies. When a new visitor comes, increase count and set endless cookie to him. When he will press F5, you will see that cookie is already set and do not increment the counter.